# Shortest distance between two joggers

Tags: derivatives, maxima-minima

**Question**

Two joggers, $A$ and $B$, start at either end of a $100$ m track. $A$ runs horizontally towards the other end at $3$ m/s and $B$ runs diagonally at $5$ m/s. The diagonal forms an angle of $30$ degrees with the track. What is the closest the two joggers can get to each other?

Hint: Use Pythagoras' theorem to find the the distance between the two joggers as a function of time.

**My working**

Let the shortest distance between the joggers be $S$.

$$\begin{aligned}
S & = \sqrt{(5t)^2 - (100 - 3t)^2}\\
& = \sqrt{16t^2 + 600t - 10000}\\
\implies \frac {ds} {dt} & = \frac 1 2 (16t^2 + 600t - 10000)^{-\frac 1 2} (32t + 600)
\end{aligned}$$

When $$\frac {ds} {dt} = 0,$$
$$32t + 600 = 0.$$

However, this gives a negative value of $t$, which obviously cannot be true.

Where have I gone wrong? I am thinking that my interpretation of the shortest distance probably has some issues. Any intuitive explanations as to what the solution should be will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Just a general tip, when differentiating distances to find extrema, it is usually much easier to differentiate $S^2$, and this will yield the same result.

Comment: @egglog yeah I know haha... but the issue here is I am probably misinterpreting the problem or something... I doubt it's gotta do with my differentiation skills

Comment: You haven't used the fact that $B$ runs at an angle of $30$ degrees to the track. Let $A$ be at $(0, 0)$ and $B$ at $(100, 0)$. Although not specified I assume the $x$-coordinate of $B$ is decreasing. Then, $A$ is at $(3t, 0)$ and $B$ is at $(100 - 5t\cos30, 5t\sin30)$ at time $t$.

Their distance vector is therefore $d = (100 - (3+\frac{5}{2}\sqrt{3})t , \frac{5}{2}t)^T$, and so $|d|^2 = (100 - (3+\frac{5}{2}\sqrt{3})t)^2 + (\frac{5}{2}t)^2$

One may now differentiate $|d|^2$ with respect to $t$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

The given hint says to apply Pythagoras.

$A$ travels horizontally towards $B's$ original position whereas $B$ travels diagonally. So after time $t$, if $B$ has reached point $C$ and $A$ has reached point $D$,

$BC = 5t, AD = 3t$

Dropping perp from $C$ to $AB$,

$CE = BC/2 = \dfrac{5t}{2}, BE = \dfrac{5 \sqrt3 ~t}{2}$

$DE = 100 - \left(3t + \dfrac{5 \sqrt3 ~t}{2}\right)$

Distance between new positions of $A$ and $B$ is,

$ \displaystyle CD^2 = CE^2 + DE^2 = \frac{25 t^2}{4} + \left(100 - \left(3t + \dfrac{5 \sqrt3 ~t}{2}\right)\right)^2$

Now take derivative and equate to zero to minimize $CD^2$ (or $CD$)

You should get minimum distance at $~t \approx 12.22$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am still a little unclear about why $CD$ is the shortest distance and not $CE$? Being the hypothenuse, isn't $CD$ always greater than $CE$?

Comment: If that's the answer then you will get a value of $t$ such that $DE = 0$ but we cannot assume so upfront. Say when $A$ and $B$ are on a line perp to $AB$, $A$ is at $E'$ and $B$ is at $C'$. So while you know $CE \lt CD$ but how do you know $C'E' \lt CD$? The point $C'$ when they are on a vertical line could be way above $C$ on the diagonal.

Comment: Oh! That's right! Thank you!